# Add Tailwind to a custom Wordpress Gutenberg React block

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, tailwind-css, gutenberg-blocks

I want to start developing custom React components for implementing on my wordpress site with Gutenberg blocks.

I have set up a custom block using the official [create-block](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/create-block) tool by Wordpress. I also want to add Tailwind to my block but I can't figure out how it works. I am setting up Tailwind and creating the config files but when I run npm start, the styles are not applied.

Has anyone figured out how to use Tailwind with the React Gutenberg blocks?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you already have a working WP plugin following the paradigm of create-block.

[Install Tailwind using postcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss):

```
npm I -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwind init -p
```

The `-p` argument creates a default postcss configuration, which will do. Create-post does not provide one.

We then edit the tailwind configuration file to include all src js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The basic tailwind configuration is now ready.

In the src block, we add an `edit.css` or `style.css` and import them in `edit.js` and `save.js`. After build, each css file generates an `index.css` and `style.css`, the former gets loaded in the editor and the latter in the front-end ([documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/)). Each css file should have:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

In case of having multiple blocks in a single plugin under `src`, I have found that all of them should have the above statements in their CSS files if we want tailwind build to generate classes for them.

Regarding the build operation. I have found that webpack autoloads postcss and generates tailwind build during normal wp-scripts start and build.

In any case, I am using a custom webpack config file, which I also found that it gets loaded automatically if it exists. It does not contain anything regarding postcss, I only post it for the sake of completeness.

```
/** @type {import('webpack').defaultConfig} */
const defaultConfig = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');
const path = require('path');

/** @type {import('webpack').Configuration} */
module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/build'),
    },
};
```

I hope this is helpful. If I have omitted anything let me know.